# Can exception types be generic?

Tags: generics, exception, f#

I've tried the following, which don't work.

```
exception MyError<'a> of 'a
exception 'a MyError of 'a
```

Do I have to use the long form:

```
type MyError<'a>(value) =
  inherit System.Exception()
  member this.Value : 'a = value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the specification, you have to use the long form. I didn't find any explanation why that's the case, but the grammar for exception declarations looks like this (and maybe also hints why the behavior is as you described):

> exception-defn := attributes<sub>opt</sub> **exception** union-type-case-data
>
> union-type-case-data :=
>       ident                                                        *(nullary union case)*
>       ident **of** type * ... * type      *(n-ary union case)*
>       ident : uncurried-sig                *(n-ary union case)*

This is quite interesting, because it suggests that exception declarations are more like *discriminated union cases* than like types. I guess you can think of an exception declaration...

```
exception MyExn of int
```

...as a declaration adding new case to the standard `System.Exception` type (if it was a discriminated union). In this case you wouldn't expect to be able to use a generic type parameter:

```
type System.Exception = 
  | ...
  | MyExn of int
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Yes, when you think of it as an additional DU case for `Exception` it makes sense that it can't be generic. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel - I think it is most likely a mismatch between the ML-view and .NET-view of exceptions (but I don't know ML background well enough).

Comment: Yes, it seems a generic syntax would be possible since you can declare a generic class that inherits from `Exception`.