# Parameterized exception type

Tags: f#, custom-exceptions

In Scala I can generate an exception that carries a value of some type parameter `A` via `case class MyException[A]( value: A ) extends Exception`

Is there a way to define a similar type in F#?

`exception MyException<'a> of 'a` is not possible as far as I can see. Do I need to generate a separate exception for each type it should carry? I guess I could define a `type T = INT int | BOOL bool | PAIR T * T` and use it if I don't want to have multiple exceptions, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099027/can-exception-types-be-generic